# How can I open a specific node of a CHM (Windows Help) file in the command line?

Tags: command-line, chm, help-files

Specifically, the CHM help file I'm thinking about is the [PHP User Manual](http://php.net/download-docs.php). I would like some way to be able to open this file directly to a given function reference (node) in the document. Like this:

```
C:\> php_manual_en.chm json_encode
```

Only that ↑ syntax isn't correct -- that just ends up opening the manual to the TOC. Can CHM files accept command line arguments? Is there some way to open them directly to certain nodes?

Answer (score 2):

Try to extract your favorite topic address (URL) from the CHM help viewer window and copy to the clipboard:

**mk:@MSITStore:D:\php_manual_en.chm::/res/function.json-encode.html**

Copy into the cmd text box and press ENTER - the single topic opens in IE (*see attached snap 1*)

Add a praefix hh.exe for using the CHM help viewer like:

**hh.exe mk:@MSITStore:D:\php_manual_en.chm::/res/function.json-encode.html**

You'll see the help viewer with Table of Contents (TOC) in the navigation pane and the topic.

Snap 1
[image]

Snap 2

[image]